# JBoss Clustered Application Freezes and Apache mod_cluster config has some warnings

Tags: apache, jboss, mod-cluster

I have my JBoss Application in cluster. When I start my domain.sh in all the nodes and run the application. My Application freezes even for normal db transactions from App.

When I observed my Apache I'm getting some warnings. Is this warnings are causing the problem, if so what is the salvation......

Here is my Apache Configuration...... I had followed minimal configuration which was given jboss mod_cluster documentation....

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so


<VirtualHost 10.252.103.77:80>
<Location />
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Location>
<Location /mod_cluster-manager>
SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Location>
KeepAliveTimeout 60
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
ManagerBalancerName mycluster
ServerAdvertise On
EnableMCPMReceive
</VirtualHost>
```

When I start or restart my Apache Web Server I'm getting following WARN's.......

```
~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: [Mon Dec 07 12:19:17 2015] [warn] module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Dec 07 12:19:17 2015] [warn] module proxy_ajp_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.252.103.77 for ServerName
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

I had copied all the modules which were used to the appropriate modules directory....... My domain runs on Redhat Enterprise Linux 64 bit...... So I had copied x86_64 bit version of .so files....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had commented following .so modules as those were already loaded..... Although it is just WARN for proxy module, it is unappropriated as couple of modules were loaded and works in `dual`mode....

```
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```

As I copied appropriate modules (x86_64) required.... fresh `proxy_ajp` `proxy` modules is in function instead of default ones.... SO JBoss cluster config succeeds.......

Comment: `x86_64` is Intel `x86` 32-Bit Compatible 64-Bit version. Please use command `uname -a` and appropriately use the libraries(.so files). If your os 64-Bit then don't go for `x86_64` rather go for `64-Bit`. If it is `i586` or lower use 32-Bit version of libraries(.so files). Basically AMD 64 bit processor gave compatibility 32-Bit intel x86 instruction set as well,- hence uses `x86_64` version of o.s. Else 64-Bit AMD version of o.s. needs to be loaded. That's why `x86_64`, so Intel 64-Bit, 32-Bit processor can also be used in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Messages: 
`[Mon Dec 07 12:19:17 2015] [warn] module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Dec 07 12:19:17 2015] [warn] module proxy_ajp_module is already loaded, skipping`

are completely harmless.

Message:
`httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.252.103.77 for ServerName` could affect your domain name based redirections and SSL certificates issued for a particular domain, but it has little to nothing to do with mod_cluster's operation.

Comment: We haven't configured FQDN. In my case Apache version is `[Web-01~]$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  3 2015 12:06:14
` And when this warn comes I have problem in my Deployed App like it freezes. Maybe my Cluster Config is not stable enough. However I hope even if it is WARN, it might break the cluster bridge. Not every code is so proper, particularly when we work across and in case of interoperability. After I sort out this WARNs my App is running stably. There are other issues but weren't like it frozen.